# Casting BigInt to Int in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-zeppelin

Hi I'm trying to cast a `BigInt`to an `int`in order to generate [Rating](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/Rating.html) classes. 
I only want to use instances that are small enough to fit into an in I use the following code:

```
val tup=rs.select("kunden_nr","product_list") 
val rdd=tup.rdd.map(row=>(row.getAs[BigInt](0),row.getAs[Seq[Int]](1)))
val fs=rdd.filter(el=>el._1.isValidInt)
fs.count()
rdd.count()
```

The fs count delivers the following exception in Zepplin:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to scala.math.BigInt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting is like changing "the glasses" your code use to represent what is referenced by your value and not actually changing the referenced content nor changing the reference to point to a new `BigInt` instance.

That implies that you need to get your value with the type it really has and then build a `BigInt` instance from it:

```
BigInt(row.getAs[Long](0))
```

Following the same reasoning, you can create an `Int` instance from the `Long` as follows:

```
row.getAs[Long](0).toInt
```

But it might overflow the integer type representation range.

Comment: Sorry but I need an Int. So the chain is BigInt=>Int

Answer (score 1):

When I use below to cast , the value of number will be changed!

```
table.col("id").cast("long") //java
```

Answer (score -2):

I noticed that the overflow is happening for me fairly often with `.toInt`
so I tried Adding the remainder and the quotient.

```
((rec.getLong(0) % Int.MaxValue) + (rec.getLong(0) / Int.MaxValue)).toInt
```

This was better as I was getting 232 unique values in place of 234 but with toInt I was getting 6 unique values in place of 234.